# Duplicating a postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

How do I make a duplicate copy of a `postgresql` database?

Some (I think) steps would be:

- stop all queries
- stop the `postgresql` daemon
- copy the database files to a new location
- **make some changes to the configuration files**
- reload the server

Any ideas what should I change in the `postgresql.conf` in order to inform the postgresql server about the new database?

Answer (score 5):

Copying files will not work.

Just `pg_dump` the database, and load it using `pg_restore` or `psql` (depending on options given to `pg_dump`).

Comment: How can I rename it?

Comment: Rename what? You dump with `pg_dump MYBASE > MYBASE.sql`, you create the duplicate with `createdb MYBASE2`, you populate it with `psql -f MYBASE.sql MYBASE2`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct all the absolute paths (if any) in the config files and the PGDATA variable (or option) in the startup script.

Answer (score 0):

As @user13185, you should use pg_dump / pg_restore.

But it's a good practice to rename your database prior to start the dump.

In order to do that, all connections to that database should be disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the storage of your data to a new place, copy the data directory to a new place. change the PGDATA viarable in the .service systemd startup file. Then stop the postgres run

`postgres initdb`

That can bring your postgres to use new directory as the data files including configurations like postgresql.conf